# imageshack / quick host for webpages?

Tags: webapp-rec, upload, hosting

if I just  want to quickly upload an html page as one would upload an image to imageshack. how would I do that?

no signing up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [ge.tt](http://ge.tt) for any kind of files; not only for html.

I uploaded a file called `hello.html` and I'm getting a link to it which looks like this:

```
http://ge.tt/4yK8elh
```

Playing around I managed to get a direct link to the file, without downloading it, through this address:

```
http://ge.tt/4yK8elh/hello.html
```

Which finally redirects you to something bigger:

```
http://get.ge.tt/4yK8elh/hello.html?d=1.BtQNmVQJdvaix0MFAzMoukyDO8TVxTh%252Fpio7wxEFvxIys0wPRT%252FTBGAi8gROVBJI5fKJlXXjy5riS8C4yTsk%252BVBD1RnL3W3ykVFltSGPtPpwGbX9S9QR2TjAHnQi6TH97HQQCLW35zVX6zmAD%252FV5FRDXHUBb0BB%252BkJqN%252FjDHJqkyUDkZ1ymCNg%252FJXhzktS6FxdJmSNKlWpJ8C3p18R4MhA%253D%253D
```

Comment: this may have to do, but it'd be nicer if I could wget it. Like wget h ttp://ge.tt/4yK8elh/hello.html   or get it somehow via the command line.. If it were a direct link then that wget line(minus the space in http!) would work on it

Comment: @barlop Actually you can.. try something like this: `wget -O hello.html http://ge.tt/4yK8elh/hello.html` but to be fair this wasn't stated in your question..!

Comment: yes you're right.. great though!  your ans deserves at least 2 votes!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Public folder](http://www.dropbox.com/help/16) of [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com). It is a file synching application and of course you will have to sign up for it, but once this is done, then you simply can copy all your html files (and all the related ones, like images, css, etc) to the Public folder that is located on your computer and you will get a public link for it. Any changes that you're making locally will be automatically updated on the web as well.

Comment: @barlop all of the above if I understood your question, which I believe is not very clear what you're asking there..

Comment: Well why not ask what it is you don't understand?  I said without signing up. So no, if it involves signing up then it won't work. And of course with signing up, then there are solutions. Signing up for a free web server obviously. I want to do this without signing up. Just upload an html file for public viewing. Not even a set of files. Just a one off file. Like many use imageshack for. But not for pictures.

Comment: @barlop fair enough :D